# get NullPointerException when calling constructor

Tags: android, class, constructor, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I have class that extends AsyncTask :

```
    public class DailyCourse extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void , Object> {
           public DailyCourse (){
           }
    }
```

I have Override necessary  functions and have my own functions too .

in main activity that implements my custom interface I try to call constructor :

```
    public class Luncher extends AppCompatActivity implements DailyCourseAsyncResponse {
              dailyCourse = new DailyCourse() ;
    }
```

note that I do this after onCreate and problem is I get this error  :

```
      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
     'java.lang.String android.content.res.Resources.getString(int)' on a 
      null object reference
```

what is the problem ?
NOTE : it's not duplicate with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) , I know what is null exception , the problem "was" I did not know why I get that in my case (solved)

Comment: The problem is definitely not in the code you provided. You are trying to access resources in a wrong way somewhere.

Comment: @RobertK. but i get error at this point when trying to call constructor , that's why I'm confused

Comment: Can we see a full crash log?

Comment: @RobertK. thank u very much , solved ! , how should I mention u in my answer ? :D

Comment: Don't worry about it, great job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem ! 
as @RobertK mentioned I was trying to access resources in a wrong way somewhere.
and "somewhere" is one of my class private final properties that I was trying to set value in wrong way . ( my Resource object was null )